# How do I make a prop optional if another prop is of a specified type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want the transform prop of this react component to be optional if the generic type argument is an `Option`

Therefore I define them like this.

```js
type Option = { value: string; label: string }
type TransformFn<T> = (item: T) => Option

type MaybeOptionalTransform<T> = T extends Option
  ? { transform?: TransformFn<T> }
  : { transform: TransformFn<T> }

type SuspendedPromise<T> = { read: () => T}

type SuspendedSelectProps<T> = {
  resource: SuspendedPromise<T[]>
  onChange?: (value: string) => void
  value?: string
} & MaybeOptionalTransform<T>


function SuspendedSelect<T>(props: SuspendedSelectProps<T>) {
  return null
}
```

Using this component as a "function" works:

```js
SuspendedSelect({
  resource: { read: () => [{ foo: 'aaa', bar: 'bbb' }] },
  onChange: value => undefined,
  transform: item => ({ label: item.foo, value: item.bar })
})

SuspendedSelect({
  resource: { read: () => [{ label: 'aaa', value: 'bbb' }] },
  onChange: value => undefined
})
```

Both these invocations works as expected, typescript gives no error.

But when I use it as a react component like this:

```js
<SuspendedSelect
  resource={{ read: () => [{ foo: 'aaa', bar: 'bbb' }] }}
  onChange={value => undefined}
  transform={item => ({ label: item.foo, value: item.bar })}
/>
```

I get a typescript error:

```
TS2322: Type '(item: Option & { foo: string; bar: string; }) => { label: string; value: string; }'
        is not assignable to type 'TransformFn<{ foo: string; bar: string; }>'.
  Types of parameters 'item' and 'item' are incompatible.
     Type '{ foo: string; bar: string; }' is not assignable to type
          'Option & { foo: string; bar: string; }'.
       Type '{ foo: string; bar: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 
           'Option': value, label

  deviation-modal.tsx(23, 7): The expected type comes from property 'transform' which is
  declared here on type 
  'IntrinsicAttributes
   & {
       resource: { read(): { foo: string; bar: string; }[]; };
       onChange?: ((value: string) => void) | undefined; value?: string | undefined;
     }
   & { transform: TransformFn<...>; }'
```

It goes away if I manually specify the type when I render the component. But I would prefer if typescript could infer the correct type by itself.

Why does typescript infer the 'incorrect' type for the transform function? And can I do anything about it?

Comment: Please make sure that your example is reproducible. There is no definition for `SuspendedPromise`

Comment: I added the definition now.

Comment: CHeck if [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpLgMm) works for you. In order to make it work with JSX, you need to overload your function

Comment: That is a neat idea! Didn't think about function overloads, and that works perfectly! Just have to make sure the definition of the transform function is included in the implementation. If you make this an answer, i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it work, you need to overload your component function instead of making conditional typings. Please keep in mind, that react component is just a regular function.

```js
import React from 'react'

type Option = { value: string; label: string }
type TransformFn<T> = (item: T) => Option

type SuspendedPromise<T> = { read: () => T }

type SuspendedSelectProps<T> = {
  resource: SuspendedPromise<T[]>
  onChange?: (value: string) => void
  value?: string
}

function SuspendedSelect<T>(props: SuspendedSelectProps<T> & { transform: TransformFn<T> }): any
function SuspendedSelect<T extends Option>(props: SuspendedSelectProps<T> & { transform?: TransformFn<T> }): any
function SuspendedSelect<T,>(props: SuspendedSelectProps<T>) {
  return null
}

SuspendedSelect({
  resource: { read: () => [{ foo: 'aaa', bar: 'bbb' }] },
  onChange: value => undefined,
  transform: item => ({ label: item.foo, value: item.bar })
})

SuspendedSelect({
  resource: { read: () => [{ label: 'aaa', value: 'bbb' }] },
  onChange: value => undefined
})

const jsx = <SuspendedSelect
  resource={{ read: () => [{ foo: 'aaa', bar: 'bbb' }] }}
  onChange={value => undefined}
  transform={item => ({ label: item.foo, value: item.bar })}
/>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpLgMm)

Also, you can check my articles: [my blog](https://catchts.com/react-props) and [dev.to](https://dev.to/captainyossarian/how-to-type-react-props-as-a-pro-2df2)